# css media statment is not working

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have this css

```
@media screen and (max-width :300px) {
  .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
    float: left;        
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

which meas that I want to change the css when the size becomes less that 300 px

I have added this meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

#### but

when I change the size of the browser to less that 300 px, these css doesn't apply. I know that because I check the firbug and checked the used css and my css haven't shown.

#### Edit

This is my **default** css

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
    float: left;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and in the firebug, I always see that one, not the one in media

Comment: why don't you set the background to a colour that way you would know if the css is applied or not

Comment: are you using bundling and minification?

Comment: @Zaki that would be agood idea, but I am 100% sure that the new css is not applied because in the firebog I can see the css and it is another css, which is i made for the general case. but here I need this special case, when the size is less that 300

Comment: Morpheus, I have never heard about them

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML of this not working so we can test the CSS against it? I cannot see why it would not work if the css selector is correct.

Comment: Morpheus, I tried, but still the same results

Comment: @DaveS i posted my css, check it please

Comment: You don't see because there are no differences between your normal css and media one. Try to add some other rule to media (like @Zaki said) to see the difference.

Comment: Morpheus, I did try to change the background but nothing happened, second, there is the second line, when I remove it I can see a huge different

Comment: I got the background but there is no changing in padding, although I make the paddnig zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media query css has the same properties as your default css and with the same values, that won't do anything. You need to set the value that must change and only that, lets say, you want to remove the padding, you then specify that in the media query, be aware that for this to work, it must be below your default css (Cascade style) or the default will take precedence. So always remember that the media query rule will be applied on top of your default, not instead.

Here is an example based on your code, and as you can see it works as it should:

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6WPP8/1/)

**Html**

```
<div class="ui-tabs">
    <nav class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <a href="#" class="ui-tabs-anchor">Link 1</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
    float: left;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: red;
    display:block;
}

@media screen and (max-width :300px) {
    .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor    {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

**Note**
Sometimes you must add the '!important' flag to the property value if it was set in the default by targeting its id.